# List Unique Dates From Google Sheets Column

Tags: date, google-sheets, unique, countif

I am trying to list out the unique dates from the "Extracted Dates" column. I ultimately want to then use COUNTIF to determine how many times each of those dates are listed but it will be so much easier if I can have the unique dates listed first.

Here is the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pyxiEi0Lrsf2VeA1vQxTRKW-xKdK0fwEumxe0z9j_W4/edit?usp=sharing

I have tried using the =UNIQUE function for the entire column, but this only ever provides the first date. I have tried several other combinations of things from other forums, but none of them have worked.

At first, I thought that the timestamp having the time listed alongside the date was the issue, so I extracted just the date using the =TO_DATE function. However this still did not produce the right result.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with QUERY, first extracting the dates with DATEVALUE:

```
=QUERY(INDEX(DATEVAL(B:B)),"SELECT Col1,COUNT(Col1) group by Col1",)
```

[image]

Comment: You'll possibly need to format the left column to show the dates as dates and not only numbers (is 46547)

Comment: Better use `format` clause inside `QUERY()` function.

Comment: Thanks for the response! It looks like that somewhat worked, but it is converted dates to numbers (I am assuming doing the math treating the date dashes as division?). I tried it with the C column instead but then it appears to be missing dates.

Comment: You can add `format Col1 'MM/DD/YYYY'` at the end of the Query, as Harun24hr suggested, too

Answer (score 0):

You can do this all by a single formula. Try-

```
=LET(x,INDEX(DATEVALUE(B2:INDEX(B2:B,COUNTA(B2:B)))),{x,BYROW(x,LAMBDA(dt,COUNTIFS(B2:B,">="&dt+time(0,0,1),B2:B,"<="&dt+time(23,59,59))))})
```

Then apply your desired date format to resultant date column like screenshot below.

[image]